# Repair file names

Tags: filesystem

How can I repair filenames that contains characters that looks like rectangulars with some numbers in it. (Translated from german umlauts)

[image]

There is a tool like convmv, but I don't know what parameters I've to set.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

First you install the convmv from

```
sudo apt-get install convmv
```

Then CD to the main directory where you have those files and folders and then type

```
 convmv -f iso-8859-7 -t utf8 -r --notest --replace ~/path/to/directory_here
```

Source Taken from : [Linux.com](http://archive09.linux.com/articles/58689)

Comment: It didn't help. I've added an example picture.